# what's the difference between Executor and ExecutorService?

Tags: java

I am wondering what's the difference between Executor and ExecutorService?

Any example will help.

Comment: *An Executor that provides methods to manage termination and methods that can produce a Future for tracking progress of one or more asynchronous tasks*...

Comment: "Execution" + "Service" == "ExecutionService".  Ergo, the difference is "Service".

Comment: This is the first result when you Google. I know reading the docs is good practice, but a concise answer helps.

Comment: Totally Agree with you @ChristopheDeTroyer, if the difference is so small why the documentation about it is so big? Ja... whatever, nice to have this concise answer here.

Comment: "closed as not a real question" - This is actually a useful question paired up with a concise answer...

Answer (score 119, accepted):

[Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) just executes stuff you give it.

[ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) adds startup, shutdown, and the ability to wait for and look at the status of jobs you've submitted for execution on top of Executor (which it extends).

Comment: This is a perfect answer, short and clear.

Comment: One addition is that Executor cannot handle Callables whereas ExecutorService has a submit method which does take a Callable as an argument.

Comment: if all that Executor provides is a single execute method why create a separate Interface for that? why not just have that method in the ExecutorService instead and not have Executor interface at all ..