# When should I use Executor over ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am learning multi-threading and I came across [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052317/whats-the-difference-between-executor-and-executorservice).

- [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) just executes stuff we give it.
- [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) adds startup, shutdown, and the ability to wait for and look at the status of jobs we've submitted for execution on top of Executor (which it extends).

I am still trying to wrap my head around the usage of Executor and ExecutorService.

1. When would be a scenario when I would use Executor over ExecutorService? Can I use ExecutorService everywhere?
2. Is there a way to add an explicit `shutdown` for an Executor's execute or what is the general practice around it?

The below code where I use `Executor` doesn't terminate. Is this the right way to use an Executor or am I missing something here? How can I properly terminate the code? I am aware that Executor doesn't have a `shutdown`. So is it expected for this program to not terminate?

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        executor.execute(() ->
                System.out.println("Executor Class: " +
                        Thread.currentThread().getId() + ", Name: " +
                        Thread.currentThread().getName()));
    }
}
```

If I replace the above with `ExecutorService` and add a `shutdown`, the program terminates fine.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        executor.submit(() ->
                System.out.println("ExecutorService Class: " +
                        Thread.currentThread().getId() + ", Name: " +
                        Thread.currentThread().getName()));
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: `ExecutorService` interface extends `Executor` interface. ExecutorService provides few more additional methods for coordination like shutDown and awaitTermination. So it is based on your use case. As a good practice, you can always use `ExecutorService`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Q: When would be a scenario when I would use Executor over ExecutorService?

A: When you **know** that you are never going to use any of the `ExecutorService` methods.

There are few situations where you *wouldn't* need to manage the executor service in some way, there are few applications where you wouldn't need to manage the service.

(Hypothetically ... if you were creating your own task execution mechanism that didn't involve running the tasks in local threads, the management functions of `ExecutorService` might be a poor fit.)

---

> Q: Can I use `ExecutorService` everywhere?

A: Assuming that you instantiated an instance of `ExecutorService`, yes.

---

> Q: Is there a way to add an explicit shutdown for an Executor's execute or what is the general practice around it?

If you are asking if you can shut down the entire `Executor`, no there isn't a way.

`Executor` service is an interface.  In the general sense, it could be implemented in a way that can't be shut down at all.  But either way, if you don't know how the executor is implemented, then you don't know how to tell it to shut itself down.

(Sure ... if you know that it is likely to be a `ExecutorService`, then you *could* type cast it to `ExecutorService` and then call `ExecutorService.shutdown()`.)

On the other hand, if you are asking if you can cancel a specific task submitted by `Executor.execute`, the answer is also No.

But if you use the `ExecutorService.submit` methods, you will get a `Future` for each task.  You *may* be able to use `Future.cancel()` to stop the corresponding task from running or interrupt it if it is currently running.

Comment: thanks for the clarifications! So is it expected for my first program to not terminate?

Comment: Since the default thread factory doesn't create daemon threads ... yes.  In both cases, `main` will terminate, but the JVM will continue running.  In the 2nd case, the JVM will exit when all tasks have completed.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `ExecutorService` interface to *manage* the executor service.  This interface would normally be used by the object that creates or owns the executor service.

An object or method that just needs to execute stuff using an executor that is managed elsewhere should take parameters of type `Executor`.  You can pass an instance of `ExecutorService`, since it implements `Executor`.